# Navigation Property null With Entity Framework 4.3.1

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, navigation-properties

I'm using **Entity Framework 4.3.1** and am having some trouble with my navigation properties.

In my context, I've enabled lazy loading:

```
public MyContainer()
        : base(ConnectionString, ContainerName)
{
    this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
}
```

Also, I have made the property virtual (actually I generated it from my Model):

```
public virtual Driver Driver
{
    get { return _driver; }
    set
    {
        if (!ReferenceEquals(_driver, value))
        {
            var previousValue = _driver;
            _driver= value;
            FixupDriver(previousValue);
        }
    }
}
private Driver _driver;
```

This is in an entity called Ride. However, when I acces `myContext.Ride.Driver` it is null. This is strange because when I inspect the Ride entity during runtime I can see that the foreign key is actually filled with the ID of the expected Driver.

Is there anything extra I need to do?

When I generate a new Ride, I set the **DriverID**, but subsequently the Driver from which I get the ID is not automatically added as a Navigation Property.

---

Okay, I just solved it myself, so I'll share the answer: I needed to Attach the Driver entity back to the context. myContext.Driver.Attach(Driver). Then I could do: Ride.Driver = Driver instead of Ride.DriverID = Driver.DriverID.

In code I'm doing this:

```
db.Driver.Attach(Driver); // Driver is a public property in my class
myNewRide.Driver = Driver;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Okay, I just solved it myself, so I'll share the answer: I needed to Attach the Driver entity back to the context.
`myContext.Driver.Attach(Driver)`.
Then I could do: `Ride.Driver = Driver` instead of `Ride.DriverID = Driver.DriverID`.

Comment: PLease write this as an answer an mark it, so everybody sees that it is solved, thanks.

Comment: :-) almost what I meant. Do you see the "answer field" under your question? I thought to put your solution there, because then you are able to click afterwards "mark as answer".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I just solved it myself, so I'll share the answer: I needed to Attach the Driver entity back to the context. myContext.Driver.Attach(Driver). Then I could do: Ride.Driver = Driver instead of Ride.DriverID = Driver.DriverID